# Failed to map data for input 91913 for index IdIndex?

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, build

I am using IDEA to learn the springMVC framework, but I think I have encountered a strange problem.

Let me introduce the process of what happened.

My computer is stuck, and then I start to compile my project, the result is as follows

[image]

```
Failed to map data for input 91913 for index IdIndex
```

At the same time, another thing happened, I can not create a class, as shown below

[image]

Comment: maybe restart service is right........

Comment: What is the version of IntelliJ IDEA? May you share idea.log after reproducing that?